# DKIM: validation error: error:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:invalid padding

Tags: email, spam, dkim

We receive a lot of spam on our servers from 3rd party servers and often this spam includes the email header such as:

> DKIM: validation error: error:0407008A:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_1:invalid padding

This can be caused by many trivial things such as [incorrect line feeds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54997035/curl-rsa-padding-check-pkcs1-type-1invalid-padding) but I wanted to query about this as I can't find the correct information:

I believe this is an issue with the sender (them) rather than the receiver (us), therefore:

- 1. Is there any way our server can uniformly block or otherwise throttle emails incoming from external sources that fail DKIM? Either failing this specific error or any error?
- 2. Is it a good idea to do this (I sadly suspect not?)? How prevelant is competent DKIM currently? My quick research seems to imply it's not at all a safe way of filtering incoming emails, despite this appearing to be a common theme amongst email providers and badly set up amongst recognised spammers.
- 3. Could something like SpamAssassin check DKIM mail validity and mark accordingly?

Comment: *Half-answer: don't bother about DKIM failures specifically, but consider a DMARC milter/filter.* **A message may carry any number of signatures**, any of which could be useless (possibly only useless to you) or unverifiable (possibly others can retrieve the key). Your server shall *only* see if it can, within reasonable resource limits, find a useful, verifiable one that allows delivery otherwise restricted by policy (generally: DMARC). About other signatures, it [shall make no judgement](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6376#section-6.1).

Comment: @anx our servers have DMARC applied on outgoing mail but I'm unfamiliar with if its actually used as verification system on incoming mails.